# How to use mat-option as attribute in mat-select in angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

We are trying something like this:

```html
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="food.id" mat-option="food.name for food of foods" placeholder="Favorite food">
```

However, it doesn't work. How do I define like above?

Comment: Look at https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples. Mat-option should be element inside of mat-element ....

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to do so. You have to define it manually:

```html
<mat-select [(ngModel)]="food.id">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let name of foods" [value]="name.value">
    {{name.name}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```